# Flashvideo scrolling results in browser- & mousefreeze

Tags: freeze, flash

What causes a browser & mouse freeze when scrolling through flash videos?

Tested it on Vimeo & you tube in Firefox & chrome (browsers & flash are up to date)

Happens also, when other flash content like ads are loading

Comment: What do you mean by "*scrolling through* flash videos"

Comment: i mean jumping to another position on the timeline

Comment: Does not freeze for me... Why don't you detail us your specs?